# java library plugin - gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using gradle version 5.6.4.

Here is the snippet of my build.gradle file

```
    plugins {
      id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '2.0.0'
      id 'idea'
      id 'groovy'
      id 'java-library'
      id 'maven-publish'

    }

    dependencies {
      implementation "io.vavr:vavr:${vavrVersion}"
      api "org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:${rocksdbVersion}"
      implementation "redis.clients:jedis:${redisClientVersion}"
    }

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
}

jar {
  into("META-INF/maven/$project.group/$project.name") {
    from { generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication }
    rename ".*", "pom.xml"
  }
}
```

With this configuration, im expecting any consumer of this jar should see `org.rocksdb.jni` on their classpath and it should be part of the packaged jar. However, i dont see this behavior. 
What am i doing wrong?

When i run
`gradle clean build`. The jar does not contains `api` jar. 
How do i package it for another java application to consume this library.

i see a pom published with,

```
 <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
      <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But my consumer client does not understand this dependency.

Comment: You don't *package* it. You *publish* it to a Maven repository, where the pom.xml will tell all consumers of your jar that it has a dependency on rocksdbjni. If every library out there was a jar containing all its dependencies, jars would be huge files, and it would be impossible to deal with version conflicts.

Comment: I'm publishing it to artifactory. How will the consumer know that it has a dependency on rockdbjni? the jar contains a manifest with `Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

Comment: Because gradle also publishes a pom.xml listing the dependencies. I already explained that in the first comment.

Comment: im sorry i'm missing something here. i don't see the pom published. I'm assuming i am missing the maven-publish plugin?

Comment: And how are you publishing it? I don't see the maven-publish plugin being applied in your gradle build script. You must use gradle to publish, so that it generates the pom.xml. If you google for "gradle publishing" and click the first link, you'll find the gradle documentation about it.

Comment: `publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      groupId = ''
      artifactId = ''

      from components.java
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @JBNizet 
```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
}

jar {
  into("META-INF/maven/$project.group/$project.name") {
    from { generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication }
    rename ".*", "pom.xml"
  }
}```

Comment: I see your comments, but I don't know what you're asking.